# d3js negative and positive barplot looses its alignment when more bars added

Tags: angular, d3.js, alignment

I've wrote the following code in order to produce a bar-graph that will support both negative and positive values.

Here is the actual code that I'm using:

```
  private buildChart(){

    let _this = this;

    let coeffs:[number] = this.plotData.coeffs[0];
    let signatures:[string] = this.plotData.signature;

    var data = [], thing;

    for(var z = 0; z < coeffs.length; z++){
      thing = {};
      thing['name'] = signatures[z];
      thing['value'] = coeffs[z];
      data.push(thing)
    }

    // Create the tooltip div
    let tooltip = d3.select(this.chartElement.nativeElement).append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    let margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 30},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Add svg to
    let svg = d3.select(this.chartElement.nativeElement).
    append('svg').
    attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).
    attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom).
    append('g').
    attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    // X and Y scale
    let x = d3.scaleLinear().
    range([0, width]);
    let y = d3.scaleBand().
    rangeRound([height, 0]);

    // Create the X and Y axis
    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    // Set X and Y domain
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d:any) {return d.value;})).nice();
    y.domain(data.map(function (d:any) {return d.name;}));

    // Add the bars
    svg.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', function (d) {
      return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive");
    })
    .attr('x', function (d) {return x(Math.min(0, d.value));})
    .attr('y', function (d) {return y(d.name) + 30;})
    .attr('width', function (d) {return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0));})
    .attr('height', 45)
    // Tooltip
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 1.0);
      tooltip.html("<b>Name:</b> " + d.name + "<br/>" 
          + "<b>Value:</b> " + d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]) + "px")
      .style("top",  (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });

    // Add X axis
    svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

    // Add Y axis
    let tickNegative = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(0) + ',0)')
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll('.tick')
    .filter(function (d, i) {return data[i].value < 0;});

    tickNegative.select('line')
    .attr('x2', 6);

    tickNegative.select('text')
    .attr('x', 9)
    .style('text-anchor', 'start');

  }
```

What I realized is that when the bars are few, there is no problem with rendering them, as shown on the first image:

[image]

From the other hand, when the bars are increased in number, the graph seems a little bit misaligned as the following image shows:

[image]

I looked again and again in the code but couldn't find where this issue derives from. It seems that the Y scale is somewhat hard-coded but reading the code couldn't approve that.

Any idea/hint is welcomed.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you have a hard-coded data, that is, the `height` of the bar in this line:

```
.attr('height', 45)
```

Try using [bandwidth](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#band_bandwidth) instead.

Here is a complete [example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaleband)